# Python libraries in Azure

Tags: python, azure

I have a requirement where I have to use the Python libraries I created on my machine, in the cloud, such that whenever any new dataset is loaded, this Python library have to start acting on it.

How can I do this? Where will I put the dataset and the python codes in Azure?

Thanks,
Shyam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more possibility to do that.

1. Run your Python code on Azure Web Apps for Containers—a Linux-based, managed application platform
2. Azure Functions allows running Python code in a serverless environment that scales on-demand.
3. Use a managed Hadoop and Spark cluster with Azure HDInsights, suitable for enterprise-grade production workloads.
4. Use a friction-free data science environment that contains popular tools for data exploration, modeling, and development activities.
5. Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) offers a fully-managed Kubernetes cluster to run your Python apps and services, as well as any other Docker container. Easily integrate with other Azure services using Open Service Broker for Azure.
6. Use your favorite Linux distribution, such as Ubuntu, CentOS, and Debian, or Windows Server. Run your code with scalable Azure Virtual Machines and Virtual Machine Scale Sets.
7. Run your own Python data science experiments using a fully-managed Jupyter notebook with Azure Notebooks.

The easiest and fastest way to run your code is 1. option. Create a web app and a web job in there.

Comment: See more informations about it here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/python/